# Find $lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z^5}{(1+z-e^z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

What is $$lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z^5}{(1+z-e^z)}$$

if $g(z) = 1+z-e^z$, then $g'(0)=0$, so I'm not even allowed to use l'Hopital. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't use l'Hopital once then use it twice!

Comment: I actually did that in the first place and got 0, but I didn't know if it was even allowed, since I read somewhere that I can use it only if $g'(z)$ is not $0$ (where $g(z)$ is the denominator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$e^z-z-1=\frac{z^2}{2!}+o(z^2).$$

Comment: this is helpful, I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

As @Sammygerbil noted, you can use the rule twice viz.$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z^5}{1+z-e^z}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{5z^4}{1-e^z}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{20z^3}{-e^z}=0.$$